# Restart server after making chainges in asset.rb

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx

I added `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( design1/business-casual.css )` code to the assets.rb file . When I looked to my rail app it told me to restart my server. I am running my app under vhost in unicorn+nginx. I have restarted my nginx server but still the problem is not going away.

Comment: try service unicorn restart

Comment: @AmitBadhekaPykihStaff  it gave me this err
`Couldn't reload, starting 'cd /usr/share/nginx/html/fuitter-test && bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E development -D' instead`

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to that.
I checked my stderr log file and found that a process was already running.
So I checked to see by doing `ps aux | grep unicorn`. It showed me the process and I killed it. Then I simply ran `service unicorn_appname start`.